# How to hide chapter/section/subsection/subsubsection content (leaving titles visibles also in toc), with one common command?

Tags: formatting, comments

For a certain reason I need to hide the content of some chapters/sections/subsections/subsubsections for a few time during my document writing, in such a way that the titles should be visible, also in the table of content.

The solution I know is to use the `comment` environment, for example:

```
\chapter{test chapter 1}
\begin{comment}
dummy text bla bla bla
\end{comment}

\section{test section}
\begin{comment}
dummy text bla bla bla
\end{comment}

\chapter{test chapter 2}
\begin{comment}
dummy text bla bla bla
\end{comment}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same with just one command, so hiding the content until the next chapter/section etc., for example as shown below ?

```
\chapter{test chapter 1}
\hidecontent
dummy text bla bla bla

\section{test section 1}
\hidecontent
dummy text bla bla bla

\chapter{test chapter 2}
\hidecontent
dummy text bla bla bla
```

Comment: Not the answer you are looking for precisely, but you could use `\input{chapter1body.tex}` and put all content in `chapter1body.tex`. Then it would be straightforward to comment it out.

Comment: @MatthiasArras Or `\inputonly{somethingelse}`.